# How to determine local extrema for $f(x) = x\cdot \sin(x) ^ {\sin(x)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry, maxima-minima

I need to find the local extrema points of the following function:
$f(x)  = x\cdot\sin(x) ^ {\sin(x)}$

I was already able to derive to this function: 
$f'(x)  = x (\ln(\sin(x))+1)\cos(x)\sin(x)^{\sin(x)}+\sin(x)^ {\sin(x)}$

Comment: find $x$ where $f'(x)$ is equal to $0$. Then assess the sign change while crossing the roots

Comment: This function is defined in $\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb Z}[2n\pi,2n\pi+\pi]$.

Comment: You first have to take into considerations the extreme points of the intervals

Comment: Then your equation $f'=0$ inside these intervals is *highly non-linear and trascendental*...

Comment: I don't think much can be said, except numerically

Comment: Well, you might want to prove that, with the possible exception of a finite number of intervals, there are always exactly $5$ extremal points inside each of them.

Comment: In fact, the only exception is the interval $[0,\pi]$, which contains only $4$ extreme points.

Comment: Approximate $x^*$ s.t. $f'(x^*)=0$ using some numerical method.

Comment: You can also say that in the interval $[2n\pi,2n\pi+\pi]$ the interior extremal points are almost $2n\pi+\pi/2$, $2n\pi+\arcsin(1/e)$ and $2n\pi+\pi-\arcsin(1/e)$

Comment: First you need to consider that a negative number to an irrational power is usually not real, so what do you mean by "extrema"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain of $f$ is where $\sin x>0$ i.e. $$\bigcup_{n\in \Bbb Z}(2n\pi ,2n\pi +\pi)$$ on this domain by equaling the derivative to zero we obtain $$\sin x^{\sin x}=0\\\text{or}\\ x(1+\ln \sin x)\cos x+1=0$$where $\sin x^{\sin x}=0$ is always impossible and the second equation **can only be solved numerically**. Here is a sketch of the function[image]